# How does the flag works?

Tags: c

Here is my code. I wanna make it work if the user enters y it will contunue the loop,otherwise if they press q the program exits. I saw many people using flags and i thought that's great,so i tried to do something but i don't know why it's not working. I tried using break; and continue; but still the output is not what i want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){



int broj1,broj2,zbir;
  char exit;
  int flag = 0;

  while(!flag){
  printf("Enter numbers: \n");
  scanf("%d %d",&broj1,&broj2);
  zbir = broj1+broj2;
  printf("N1 + N2 is: %d\n",zbir);

  printf("Type 'q' if you want to exit or 'y' to continue: ");
  scanf("%c",&exit);


  if(exit=='q')
  flag=1;

  if(exit=='y')
  flag=0;

}


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: broj1 = number1,broj2=number2,zbir=sum. For you that don't feel familiar with the language i am using.

Comment: `scanf("%c",&exit);`. That will leave a character in the buffer. The input is actually `"y\n"`. Always check the return value of functions, particularly `scanf` in this case.

Comment: Typo, by "buffer" I mean input stream.

Comment: What do you mean by "the output is not what i want"? Please tell us what you expect and what you get. You might like to take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `exit = getch();`, instead of scanf, and also if you use getch() , the user does not need to hit Enter after typing y or q, if you want to keep your scanf you can add `fflush(stdin);` before it (to remove Enter from last scanf call)

Comment: Note that `fflush` on input streams (such as `stdin`) is not defined in standard C. In any case, it's generally a bad idea to get rid of the newline after `scanf` by flushing even if your platform supports it as an extension. Just read until the newline, or prefix each following `scanf` format string with an extra space (e.g., `" %d"`) to eat the whitespace. Or, better yet, use `fgets` for line-based input instead of `scanf`.